# undefined method `permit_weak_imports' with brew install

Tags: github, homebrew, brew

I am unable to install [hub](https://github.com/github/hub). By running

```
https://github.com/github/hub/issues/new
```

I get the error

```
 Error: undefined method `permit_weak_imports' for #<Object:0x0000000220d0d0>
```

**What is the origin of this error and how to fix it?**

Full output:

```
$ brew install hub
==> Installing dependencies for hub: go
==> Installing hub dependency: go
==> Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.1.src.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/user/.cache/Homebrew/go-1.7.1.tar.gz
Error: undefined method `permit_weak_imports' for #<Object:0x0000000220d0d0>
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/Linuxbrew/linuxbrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/go.rb:59:in `install'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:130:in `block in install'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:930:in `block in brew'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:1553:in `block in stage'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:92:in `block in unpack'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/fileutils.rb:37:in `mktemp'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:88:in `unpack'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:81:in `stage'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:1543:in `stage'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:926:in `brew'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:108:in `install'
/home/user/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:177:in `<main>'
```

Comment: For me `brew install hub` works fine. What is the output of `brew doctor`? You can also try to delete the cache at `/home/user/.cache/Homebrew`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update Homebrew
execute command -> brew update